# Prove the volume of a ball with radius approaching 0

Tags: integration, limits-without-lhopital

Let f be continuous and let Br be the ball of radius r > 0 centered at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.
Let V (Br) be the volume of Br. Prove that
$$\lim_
{r\to0}
\frac{1}{V(Br)}\
\iiint_{Br} \ f(x,y,z)
dV = f(x_0, y_0, z_0).$$

I can visualise the image of $x^2+y^2+z^2\to0$ is a very small ball that the volume can be neglegible so the integral will be apprx = the real value of the function at the center of the ball.

My question is how to represent my idea in a more formal way.

Comment: What is $B$ in integral?!

Comment: sorry, it is Br, I just edited

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Bigl|\frac{1}{V(Br)}\iiint_{Br} f(x,y,z)\,dV-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\Bigr|\le\frac{1}{V(Br)}\iiint_{Br}\bigl|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\bigr|\,dV.
$$
Now **IF** $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$...

Comment: why do you have to put everything in absolute value? and why the RHS > LHS?

Comment: When you try to prove $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=\ell$ you try to make $|h(x)-\ell|$ small; $h(x)-\ell<\epsilon$ is not enough. As for the second question, I hope you konw $|\int f|\le\int|f|$. Also, $\int_{B_r}dV=V(B_r)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not get the idea of the proof

Comment: Ther result is false if $f$ is not continuous at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, so in the following I assume continuity. 1) Write $$f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\frac{1}{V(B_r)}\int_{B_r}f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\,dV$$. 2) Get the inequality in the answer above. 3) Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)|<\delta$ implies $|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)|<\epsilon$.